# Can't get Exodus (crypto wallet) to open in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bitcoin

- I can't get Exodus (crypto wallet) to open.
- I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo pc - 16GB memory, 2TB hard-disk
- Because I was having booting problems I recently wiped my hard-drive and re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 - and retrieved my home dir and all sub-directories from an external backup.
- I re-downloaded Exodus (latest version 20.5.22) from Exodus.io - I can see the files but can't get it (Exodus) to open - I attach a screenshot of what I see in File manager.
- Thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: Did you set executable permissions to exodus.desktop with "chmod +x exodus.desktop" ? Moreover (and it may be not related to the previous question), if you press the nine dots app grid and find Exodus, does it appear? If yes, what happens if you click it?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - greatly appreciated. I had not done "chmod +x exodus.desktop" but have done now - it made little difference - opened a seemingly unrelated file entitled "Text Import - [exodus.desktop]. Exodus does not appear when using the nine-dots app grid. Do you think there is some package that I need to add (via the Terminal)? Thanks once again.

Comment: Did you download the zip package, unzip it, place the folder in your home directory., and run Exodus by double-clicking on the "exodus.desktop" file as per https://support.exodus.io/article/36-how-do-i-install-exodus

Comment: Yes, I did that.  I did it a number of ways too - via Chromium and Firefox and in Downloads dir and home dir.  The same result for all of them. I wonder if I am not missing a "package" - I say this because the "exodus.desktop" icon is different from what it usually is - you will see this from the screenshot I gave.  I have also done this on my laptop (which is also running Ubuntu 20.04 - same result.  Is there perhaps a way of doing it from the Terminal using cli?

Comment: And I'm having the same problem with bitcoin core.  It used to run nicely on Ubuntu 18.04 but can't get it to open now.  Hmmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.
I have managed to solve the problem:

How I updated Exodus on 2021.04.16:

```
1) Went to website - Exodus.com/Download
2) Downloaded latest version; I chose  "Download Linux app (.deb)" 
3) Opened a Terminal and entered:
    1) cd ./"directory that I downloaded to"
    2) sudo dpkg -i exodus_21.4.12_amd64.deb
5) This did the trick. Then opened the app by typing "exodus" in the command line or going to the "Applications centre" - the icon with 9 dots, bottom left of screen - and finding the Exodus app there.
```

## Hope this helps?

Answer (score -1):

This one work for me and its a work around for problem.
29

If you're looking for a reliable GUI way to install .deb files, use `gdebi`.

To see if you already have it installed on your system...

```
dpkg -l gdebi | grep ii
```

If it's not there, install it this way...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```